# Valgrind not working getting error

Tags: kernel, compiling

```
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ uname -r
4.10.0-42-generic
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$

rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ sudo make clean
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ sudo ./configure --host=powerpc-pc-linux LDFLAGS=-static CC=/opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc_85xx-gcc CXX=/opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc_85xx-g++ --enable-tls --prefix=/home/rajeshsingh/valgrind_bins/ --exec-prefix=/home/rajeshsingh/valgrind_bins
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ sudo make
rajeshsingh@rajesh-dt:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.13.0$ sudo make install
```

After that I am makeing this as tar.gz file and copying on device and uncomprees it.

On Device:

```
tar -xjvf valgrind.tar.gz

mv valgrind_bins/bin/valgrind /etc/bin/
cp valgrind_bins/lib/valgrind/default.supp /etc/lib/valgrind/
VALGRIND_LIB=/tmp/valgrind_bins/lib/valgrind/
export VALGRIND_LIB
/etc/bin/valgrind ls
```

O/P:

```
bash-4.3# /etc/bin/valgrind ls
==1797== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1797== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1797== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1797== Command: ls
==1797== 

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld.so.1
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld.so.1
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:  
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

I added some check in m_redir.c file and compile and loaded valgrind.

```
+#if CI_HACK_strlen
      add_hardwired_spec(
         "ld.so.1", "strlen",
         (Addr)&VG_(ppc32_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen),
         complain_about_stripped_glibc_ldso
      );
+#endif

bash-4.3# mv valgrind_bins/bin/valgrind /etc/bin/
/default.supp /etc/lib/valgrind/
VALGRIND_LIB=/tmp/valgrind_bins/lib/valgrind/
export VALGRIND_LIBbash-4.3# cp valgrind_bins/lib/valgrind/default.supp /etc/lib/valgrind/
cp: can't create '/etc/lib/valgrind/': No such file or directory

bash-4.3# VALGRIND_LIB=/tmp/valgrind_bins/lib/valgrind/
bash-4.3# export VALGRIND_LIB
bash-4.3# /etc/bin/valgrind ls
==1836== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1836== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1836== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1836== Command: ls
==1836== 
==1836== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1836==    at 0x4002820: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836==    by 0x4015693: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836== 
==1836== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1836==    at 0x4002854: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836==    by 0x4015693: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836== 
disInstr(ppc): found an AltiVec or an e500 instruction 0x13C17320
that can't be handled by Valgrind.  If this instruction is an
Altivec instruction, Valgrind must be run on a host that supportsAltiVec instructions.  If the application was compiled for e500, then
unfortunately Valgrind does not yet support e500 instructions.
==1836== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x400df78.
==1836==    at 0x400DF78: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==1836== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==1836== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==1836==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==1836==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==1836== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==1836==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==1836==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==1836== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==1836== probably kill your program.
==1836== 
==1836== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==1836==  Illegal opcode at address 0x400DF78
==1836==    at 0x400DF78: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.6.so)
==1836== 
==1836== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1836==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1836==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==1836== 
==1836== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1836== 
==1836== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1836== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1836== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction
```

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using Ubuntu 17.04 and want to use valgrind version 3.13 which is available in Ubuntu 17.10. The easiest thing to do would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 and install valgrind from the default Ubuntu repositories. Ubuntu 17.04 will be End of Life within a month before this February anyway.